# How to get the attribute name and value of a select tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get all the attributes (name with value) of an option selected in a select tag using jquery/javascript

```
<select name=student>
    <option id="1" marks="80" gender="f">Abc</option>
    <option id="2" marks="80" gender="m">def</option>
    <option id="3" marks="80" gender="f">xyz</option>
</select>
```

How to get attributes of a selected option along with attribute name and value like `id="1",marks="80", gender="f"`

Comment: the quality of this question could be improved by including the code you've tried so far, showing the research effort invested

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this, using jquery:

```
// This represents an Attribute.
function Attribute(name, value){
   this.name = name;
   this.value = value;
}

// This is the array of element's attributes
var attributes = [];

$("#elementsId").each(function() {
    $.each(this.attributes, function() {
        if(this.specified) {
            attributes.push(new Attribute(this.name, this.value))
    }
  });
});
```

In the following snippet, I apply this for the first option.

```js
$(function(){
   
    // This represents an Attribute.
    function Attribute(name, value){
       this.name = name;
       this.value = value;
    }
    
    // This is the array of element's attributes
    var attributes = [];
    
    $("#1").each(function() {
        $.each(this.attributes, function() {
            if(this.specified) {
                attributes.push(new Attribute(this.name, this.value))
        }
      });
    });
  
    for(var i=0; i<attributes.length; i++)
      document.write("name: "+attributes[i].name+" value: "+attributes[i].value+"</br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name=student>
<option id="1" marks="80" gender="f">Abc</option>
<option id="2" marks="80" gender="m">def</option>
<option id="3" marks="80" gender="f">xyz</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you point me to the specification for the `attributes` property? I can't seem to find it on MDN. Additionally, it may be worth pointing out the confusion between an *HTML attribute* and a `data-` attribute. Seeing as marks & gender don't appear to have anything to do with the DOM element itself, these definitely should be stored in `data-`

Comment: @RGraham [Element.attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.attributes) returns a [NamedNodeMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NamedNodeMap) which contains a collection of [Attr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Attr) instances

Comment: @Rhumborl Thanks a lot! Googlefail :)

Comment: @RGraham Rhumborl got in earlier :)

Comment: And obviously to get the selected option instead of just the first one, you can replace `$("#1").each` with `$('select[name=student] option:selected').each`